# "Docker compose: command not found" - Despite configuring the path and making file as executable

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am new to Docker. I would like to run a docker-compose file. I have my docker-compose installed and please find below the details

```
which docker-compose
# returns usr/local/bin/docker-compose
docker-compose -v
# returns docker-compose version 1.24.0, build 0aa59064
```

I was referring the STACK OVERFLOW posts and was able to find something regarding the PATH variable, so I have also placed my docker-compose in /usr/bin/ path as well.
So, the below command

```
find /usr/bin/ -name "docker-compose"
# returns /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

In addition, I made the files under both paths executable by using "chmod +x" command under respective folders.

So when I finally try to execute my docker-compose.yml file, I get the below error

```
sudo ./docker-compose up - I am executing this command right in the folder where docker-compose.yml file is present
```

And I get the below error,

```
sudo: ./docker-compose: command not found
```

How can I execute my docker-compose.yml file without any issues and start my containers. Am I making any mistakes while making it as an executable file?

Comment: https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/docker-without-sudo.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `sudo docker-compose` instead. The `./` means that the shell you're in will look in the current directory. If you aren't inside /usr/local/bin or /usr/bin, it will fail.

Also if you're on linux, you should follow the following instructions to avoid having to run docker as root: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/

Comment: Hello @Christian Elowsky - Thanks for the response.  It works. 1) Is it not recommended to run docker-compose as sudo in linux? 2) Shouldn't ./ always consider the current directory? why does it depend on /usr/bin/ etc?

Comment: `./foo` is _only_ the current directory and never considers anywhere else.  As for `sudo` access, consider that you can trivially `docker run` a root shell with the entire host filesystem mounted read-write, and make your own decision on security vs. convenience.

Comment: Ultimately, the docker daemon requires the same privileges as root, so the directions I linked to are more of a convenience. You can look up info on the attack surface of the docker daemon [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface). As far as your second question goes, `./` does always consider the current directory, which I think is part of the problem you experienced. It seems like the `docker-compose` executable was in either `/usr/local/bin/` and/or `/usr/bin`, but not in the directory that you were executing the command from.

Comment: But as I downloaded docker-compose, I had a file which is named as "docker-compose". Apart from that, I also have another docker-compose.yml file which contains details of the containers that I would like to start. So I thought the 1st file was just like a config file. 2nd file is something which I should be executing to run the containers. 1st file was in /usr/local/bin and 2nd file was in current directory. What is the diff between these two files? Am I missing something